# How can I write an if statement in ruby so that something happens between certain times.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I want to display a message in my app only between certain times in my timezone. 
I'm stuck on what the best way to do this is.

So far I have:

```
 <% if 09:00 UTC-06:00 =< Time.current =<+ 19:00 UTC-06:00 %>
     // Display this message
 <% end %>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You can always use `between?`

It's a nifty little method

```
Time.current.between?('09:00 UTC-05:00', '19:00 UTC-05:00')
```

It returns true / false so it would respond nicely to your if

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of picking out the hour and checking if it's in a certain range:

```
(9..19).include?(Time.current.hour)
```

If you want to have multiple messages for different times of day:

```
case (Time.current.hour)
when 0..9, 21..23
  "Late"
when 9..19
  "Prime"
else
  "Regular"
end
```

Comment: Does this take into account the timezone?

Comment: It uses whatever time-zone `Time.current` emits, which can be dependent on the `Time.zone` setting of your current request. If you want it agnostic: `Time.current.utc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
time = Time.new
if time.hour >= 9 && time.hour < 19
    // Your code
end
```

Comment: Rails by default uses your OS's time zone.